# Cntlmd not starting under systemd on Centos 7.1

Tags: centos7, systemd

Had a weird error trying to start `cntlmd` on Centos 7.1.

systemctl start cntlmd` results in the following in the logs (and yes, becomming is exactly how it's spelt in the logs :)):

> systemd: Started SYSV: Cntlm is meant to be given your proxy address and becoming

Weird thing is:

- that it did run initially after installation.
- The exact same config works perfectly on another machine (provisioned with Chef so 100% same config).
- If I run it in the foreground it works but through systemd, not.

To "fix" it, I had to manually remove and reinstall, whereupon it worked again.

Anybody seen this error (Google reveals nothing) and know what's going on?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this when rebooting a machine. It would be running and once rebooted (is enabled) would not start up as per the error above. I have to remove cntlm and install again to fix. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @selalerer 0.35.1 from the epel repo. Also tried cntlm-0.92.3-1.x86_64.rpm from SourceForge link. SELinux is in permissive mode.

Comment: This guy in the link had the same problem with version 0.35.1-9. The -9 in the version means that it is not actually 0.35.1 but a version with more updates that RedHat added. It seems he built version 0.92 on his own (didn't use the RedHat version) and it worked for him.

https://sourceforge.net/p/cntlm/bugs/34/

Comment: @selalerer I'll build and see what happens...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I realised that the `/var/run/cntlm` directory seemed to be "removed" after every boot. Turns out the `/var/run/cntlm` directory is never *created* by systemd-tmpfiles on boot (thanks to [this SO answer](https://serverfault.com/a/547127/174775)), which then resulted in:

```
Feb 29 06:13:04 node01 cntlm: Using following NTLM hashes: NTLMv2(1) NT(0) LM(0)
Feb 29 06:13:04 node01 cntlm[10540]: Daemon ready
Feb 29 06:13:04 node01 cntlm[10540]: Changing uid:gid to 996:995 - Success
Feb 29 06:13:04 node01 cntlm[10540]: Error creating a new PID file
```

because `cntlm` couldn't write it's pid file because `/var/run/cntlm` didn't exist.

So to get systemd-tmpfiles to create the `/var/run/cntlm` directory on boot you need to add the following file in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/cntlm.conf`:

```
d /run/cntlm   700 cntlm cntlm
```

Reboot and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Anybody know where I can log this bug for the cntlm package?

Comment: Thanks. bug seems to be still there for Red Hat 7.3. Adding the line fixed it for me!